# Pegando IP LAN para envio com ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, plugin, activex

Preciso pegar o ip "LOCAL" (LAN), usando o javascript. Acontece que tenho uma aplicação em servidores meus, porém um cliente solicitou um serviço customizado. Preciso recuperar o ip local do cliente pela internet e mandar para o banco de dados em meus servidores com ajax. Preciso saber como poderia fazer com o ActiveX ou Java para pegar a informação localmente e colocar em uma variável javascript para que eu possa efetuar uma chamada AJAX para carregar a informação.

> Exemplo: IP Local: **192.168.1.1** | IP Wan: **182.236.10.25**

O ip wan é fácil de recuperar, eu preciso do IP Local (Lan).

Answer (score 1):

Creio que não tem como fazer isso, pois o endereçamento local é uma forma do seu roteador distribuir 1 endereço WAN para varias maquinas na LAN através da NAT. O endereço local é gerenciado pelo roteador e é somente acessível por aqueles que estão no mesmo nível da rede. Todas as maquinas de uma LAN que comunica com outra máquina através da WAN, ela estará comunicando com o IP WAN do roteador.

Comment: Ok @Antony Alkmin, via javascript puro eu sei que não tem como. Estou perguntando como recuperar uma informação dessas através de um ActiveX ou um Java que vai rodar localmente na máquina, onde a informação está acessível.

Answer (score 0):

Essa função te retorna o IP da maquina que está acessando a pagina:

```js
function myIP() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", false);
  xmlhttp.send();

  hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

  for (i = 0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
    ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
    if (ipAddress[0] == "IP") return ipAddress[1];
  }

  return false;

}

var IP = myIP();
if (IP != false) {
  //alert(IP);
  /* Executa sua requisicao AJAX aqui. O IP estará armazenado na variavel IP */
};
```

Comment: Ok, porém isso é para obter o ip WAN. Isso eu poderia fazer no PHP com o $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: O retorno deveria ser "192.168.1.5" por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi tua aplicação quer pegar o próprio ip local via JAVA?

```
public static String pegaIpLocal()
    {
        String s="";
        try
        {
            InetAddress in = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            s = in.getHostAddress();

        } catch(Exception j){}

        return s;
    }
```

Tenho uma solução com NODEJS, onde você poderia já fazer isso com javascript e já inserir no banco. Segue o código abaixo, se realmente quiser implementar isso em nodejs me avisa que te ajudo. É tranquilo.

```
var os=require('os'),
    mysql = require('mysql');

var ifaces=os.networkInterfaces();
var ip = [];
for (var dev in ifaces) {
  ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details){
    if (details.family=='IPv4') {
      ip.push(details.address);
    }
  });
}

var post = {
    ip : ip[0];
} 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'ipDoServidor',
  user     : 'usuario',
  password : 'senha',
});

connection.connect();
connection.query('INSERT INTO tabela SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log('Erro ao inserir ip');
    }
    console.log('Ip inserido com sucesso');
});
```

Comment: Vinicius isso precisa rodar na maquina do cliente dentro de uma página WEB, com o nodejs instalado na maquina dele funcionaria?

Comment: Funcionária sim, mas talvez então nem precise usar o servidor nodejs. O que você está usando no seu backend lá? Pois assim, a única forma de você levar isso para o "front" para enviar via ajax é fazendo primeiramente uma solicitação ajax em um arquivo do backend que te retorna o IP, sendo assim tu já chama outro ajax para enviar ao seu banco de dados...

Comment: Meu backend é um PHP que vai receber uma requisão post via javascript com o ip local.

Comment: Por exemplo, daqui agora eu iria precisar saber qual o IP Lan de sua maquina ai quando você acessar uma página minha, para isso seria necessário que vc fizesse a instalação de algo em sua maquina que iria me passar essa informação para o javascript para eu enviar uma requisição ajax. Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi então. Vou fazer o script e editar minha resposta. Vai ser como falei, vamos ter um arquivo PHP que vai te retornar o IP que vou solicitar via ajax e depois tu pega o ip e chama outro ajax para seu script php. 5 minutos. ok

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] vai me retornar o IP WAN, lembre-se...

Comment: Há entendi, mas amigo para isso você precisa ter o php na máquina do cliente, se não isso não pode ser feito!! Tu precisa ter um hospedeiro lá onde tu acessa e pega o IP. Ou o cliente precisa ter o IP fixo rodando um script local. Talvez socket resolveria seu problema, mas mesmo assim precisa de ter o server do outro lado, Ok ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18445/discussion-between-hiago-souza-and-vinicius-montanheiro).